# Help online shopping rinkeby

Tags: rinkeby

Good Day. 8 days ago I received an alleged payment in eth for rinkeby, a network that I do not know. I told the buyer until I have them in another wallet I would not send them. well 8 days ago and I don't know how rinkeby works or is it a Faucett, I think they wanted to scam me. who can clarify this matter for me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rinkeby is an Ethereum test network, completely separate from the main Ethereum network. Ether on the Rinkeby network does not have any value, and there is no way to transfer Rinkeby Ether to the Ethereum mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

So save me from a scam. The buyer sent ether and I didn't send him anything until I saw another wallet. with good reason he did not insist so much on the business. Thank you very much for the clarification.